# How to create isolations between clients in an app

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, blazor, progressive-web-apps

Hi I’m learning Blazor and I’m creating a backend & frontend app ( Blazor web assembly)
It works well, but my question is related to security.

I have user, business customer, and invoice. It's a very simple app
And user Id is a GUID and the others (business customer and invoice) are int & sequential (increment by 1 like 1,2, 3 and …)

[image]

Each user can not see the other user’s data and must not has access to them
this app has 2 parts, an API backend, and a Blazor frontend.

lets add some data like :

[image]

And End users can use the API only too without using frontend

I have in Invoice Repository:

```
Task<Invoice> GetInvoicesListAsync(int businessId);
```

and after verification users can access its invoices List

if we have a verified enduser like “Alex” (in the second  row pf user table), can be retrieve the data that its not belong to him
Because BusinessId is sequential and when he knows his business Id is 99 , he can retrieve invoices for business 100,101,102 and … just with some trying
like :

```
var lst = await GetInvoicesListAsync(101);
```

my questions are:

1-  How we can stop that? Do I need to enforce enduser to enter UserId as well for security into the API params like this :

```
Task<Invoice> GetInvoicesListAsync(Guid userId, int businessId);
```

2-  If I add userId then is that has impact on the performance? because in this case I need to do Inner join with user table too and if we have complex database then it has big impact on the performance

3- what is your advice

thanks

Comment: Performance should **never, ever** be a consideration over security.  Make the business id a checksum number of 6 - 10 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers as point list:

1. No, you don't. The method `GetInvoicesListAsync(int businessId)` is good enough from a security point of view. You need to extract the list of business per user and check if the requested business is in the list, or more simply add a *where / join* condition filtering the invoices on the businesses of the user.
2. inner join is not a problem if you have the right indexes. Use your DB *explain* query plan to verify that your query is using index and do not execute any full table scan
3. when your user call the API you need to verify the user (valid token or cookie) and to obtain teh list of the business associated, so you don't need to receive this info from the API parameters. This is the biggest concern from a security point of view. The rule for secure API is "hey API, what's my name?"

Comment: what about a big database? that we have many grand grandchildren, in this case for any extract we have to do many inner joins

Comment: How big? I'm working on a web app with industrial data with about 180gb and over 90 tables and tenth of joins without any problems. It depends how many data your join return and the execution plan you decide to use.

Comment: the database has nearly 40 tables and is not big as your DB. but is it good we expose (the sequential ids) the ids to the end-user in the URL when we want to update or .. ?

Comment: The URL for an update should be very simple because it's better to send any IDs and other data via POST in the body of the request.